Firebase Point in time recovery : field array is not recovered
On some accidentally deleted Firebase, I followed the process per below documentation of Firebase on PITR.

To recover a portion of the database, perform a stale read specifying a query-condition or using direct key lookup along with a timestamp in the past, and then write the results back into the live database

        let organisationRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference = admin.firestore().collection(ct.parent_coll_).doc("Y2nZURTmgycxTQ8TnJ")
    let readTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.parse('2024-06-27T16:30:00Z'));

    //retrieve places
    let searchPlaceQuery = parentRef.collection(ct.place_subcoll_)
    .where('api', '==', api).limit(limit);
    if (start_id != null) searchPlaceQuery = searchPlaceQuery.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), ">", start_id)

    const queryPlaceSnapshot = await firestore_root().runTransaction(
        updateFunction => updateFunction.get(searchPlaceQuery),
        { readOnly: true, readTime: readTimestamp }
    );
    console.log("querySnapshot : " + queryPlaceSnapshot.docs.length);

All data was successfully retrieved at some specific time but i have notice for all that a couple of random fields, repetitively the same ones were missing : some fields were type string and other type array
Is it something linked to indexes? only indexed fields are recovered? or a limitation in the number of fields of one document to be recovered?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pitr

If it doesn't recover exactly what you put into it, then you should reach out to Firebase support to report the issue.

Ok i will question them... this a standard PITR point retrieved 1h before when my PITR backup on 7 days was activated but other than that i am surprised a couple of field type string disappeared while some are still there...will try soon on another PITR date

Did you get any answer? Can you please share it with us?

hi, i was busy rebuilding my data and field missing,  before testing other PITR point to see if i got same observations, which is the case . So i have only sent a mail today. Up to now i have noticed a field type string, another type array string missing and a field Date being overwritten with the date used during PITR call...will provide update when any answer..
